# Copy object key in another key of same object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have list of array associated with `object`. The requirement is to make a new key that will have all key value in there.

```
var obj = {
    all:[
    obj.one,
    obj.two
    ],
 one:[
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
 ],
 two:[
 'd',
 'e',
 'f',
 'g'
 ]
}
```

//Wanted result

```
var obj = {
        all:[
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
        'd',
        'e',
        'f',
        'g'
        ],
     one:[
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
     ],
     two:[
     'd',
     'e',
     'f',
     'g'
     ]
    }
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. what have you tried?

Comment: And why are you storing all keys in another property?

Comment: Guess he has the object with "one" and "two" properties, and he wants to have an "all" property that refers to the two other properties... Such a maze, and why that? Isn't it easier to get "obj.one" and "obj.two" instead of "obj.all"? you are overcomplicating the thing imo...

Comment: Also note, `all:[
    obj.one,
    obj.two
    ]` will not copy `keys`. It will copy reference of arrays

Answer (score 1):

```
function accumulateKeyValues(obj){
    var accumulated = [];
    for(var key in obj)
        accumulated = accumulated.concat(obj[key]);
    obj["all"] = accumulated;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
function accumulateKeyValues(obj){
    var accumulated = [];
    for(var key in obj)
        accumulated = accumulated.concat(obj[key]);
    obj["all"] = accumulated;
}

var obj = {
    one:[
        'a',
        'b',
        'c'
    ],
    two:[
        'd',
        'e',
        'f',
        'g'
    ]
};

accumulateKeyValues(obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the values will be all arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could get all keys of the object and take all values for a new array.

```js
var obj = { one:['a', 'b', 'c'], two: ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'] };

obj.all = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (r, k) {
    return r.concat(obj[k]);
}, []);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```